# Execute triggers stored procedures on SqlFiddle. Mysql

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

Does SQL-fiddle facilitate execution of triggers/stored procedures?

I have been unable to execute even the simplest form of stored procedure on sqlfiddle

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProc $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Sqlfiddle does not allow executing this(above) sql in build schema, but allows create table etc

**Note:** The same syntax is working for me on my localhost using wamp with mysql 5.5.24

Can anyone guide please?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Instead of using the delimiter option (which is not a real SQL statement, but rather only a command for the mysql command prompt) use the "Query Terminator" option on SQL Fiddle to establish your delimiter.

For example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88fcf

Note the `//` dropdown below the schema box?  That's the SQL Fiddle equivalent to the mysql DELIMITER command.

Longer example with queries in the stored procedure (note that within the stored procedure, `;` is still used as a delimiter):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4db78

Full disclosure: I'm the author of SQL Fiddle.

Comment: @JakeFeasel: let me take this opportunity to thank you once more for the AWESOME SQL Fiddle. You're the man! :| Keep rocking...

Comment: @LenielMacaferi lol Thanks! Glad you like the site.  Keep up the good work on the SQL questions!

Comment: See also [this bigger example, which shows that the queries IN the procedure actually need ; to delimit](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a27/3).

Comment: @Konerak looks like using MySQL 5.6 it stop to work and showing an error: DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema panel . I'm using the example you sent http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5a27/3 . there is another thread in Portuguese about it too https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/380029/erro-ao-realizar-chamada-de-procedure-no-sql-fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12166866/26510) to work on sql fiddle, but found db-fiddle, and it seems to work.

Example in [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6cnmjTbEpx1JjufvVjm41/0)

If the above doesn't work for some reason, do the following

- Go here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/
- Enter the following SQL on the left, and `SELECT * FROM tblTest;` on the right.
- Select "MySql 5.7" or whatever in dropdown.
- Click "Run"

  ```
   DELIMITER //

   CREATE TABLE tblTest (col1 INT)//

   INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES (9)//

   CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() 
   BEGIN   
     DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 3;

     WHILE v1 > 0 DO
       INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES(v1);
       SET v1 = v1 - 1;   
     END WHILE; 
   END//

   INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES (8)//

   select * from tblTest// 
   call dowhile()// 
   select * from tblTest// 

   DELIMITER ;
  ```

Comment: Can you keep it simple by defining delimiter right before `CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() ` line like  `DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile() ` and end it right after procdure definition completes like `END//  DELIMITER ;`

Comment: You will able to use normal `;` in all other statements except the create procedure statement

Comment: Hi, I have this one and it errors out, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7iPdu4Hdzs7S8dAHeRN6TT/4