# mysql syntax error, but where?

Tags: mysql, function, syntax

I'm following some tutorials on mysql function creation but I keep getting the following error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION getstatisticscount (h VARCHAR(35),d date)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
    DECLARE tel INT;
    SELECT count(hash) into tel from statsitieken where hash=h and lastvisit between concat(d,' 00:00:00') and concat(d,' 23:59:59') group by hash;  
    RETURN tel;
   END;
```

I can for my life not find where line 5 is, but no matter which line I put it on, I keep getting this error.
If I remove this function from the sql fiddle code it's all fine.
I can't find what's wrong with it... except maybe flawed tutorials.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70f0a

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that before - http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I've added the sql fiddle link

Comment: Is it still not working for you? Where are you trying to execute these statements, in the console, in an application, or in a web or desktop based MySQL client?

Comment: Mysql version throws an error in the end that must be solved by my host. `Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Delimiter

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION getstatistics(h VARCHAR(35),d date)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
    DECLARE tel INT;
    SELECT count(hash) INTO tel
    FROM statistics
    WHERE
      hash=h
      AND lastvisit BETWEEN concat(d,' 00:00:00') AND concat(d,' 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY hash;  
    RETURN tel;
   END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

For more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Edit: basically since your stored procedure separates out statements with semicolons (;) and the method that defines your procedure ALSO uses semicolons to separate out statements, it's hard to impossible for MySQL to figure out where your procedure begins and ends. 
I also edited the SQL statement above to return the delimiter back to the default semicolon.

Comment: I'd wish it would work but it returns `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimeter //
CREATE FUNCTION getstatisticscount (h VARCHAR(35),d date)
  RETURNS' at line 1: `

Comment: It worked in HeidiSQL and MySQL command line. In SQL fiddle, try changing the query delimiter (the fourth button below the DDL box).

Comment: Can you try the suggestion in your app and not SQL fiddle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-stored-procedure-on-sqlfiddle