# Selecting sum() of likes here

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

In the following table, I'm trying to update each rows parents with the sum of their total votes.

Everything works fine here, except I'd like to do things with a `SUM()` of all the `type = 10` rather than the way I'm doing it now. Right now, what happens is this: if the total of `type = 10` change, the total of the parents do not adjust, rather they are added up. I cannot figure out how to add a `sum()` in there. I came this far. Can you help?

If you check my stored procedure, you'll see how it works.

The below stuff works fine. I'm unsure how to setup a stored procedure on `sqlfiddle` to demo it.

**My Table called `likesd` with desired results**

**These results are actually done by the stored procedure below**

```
"id"    "type"  "path"          "likes"
"1"     "1"     "0"             "20"
"2"     "1"     "0"             "20"
"3"     "2"     "1,2"           "20"
"4"     "2"     "1,2,3"         "20"
"5"     "2"     "1,2,3"         "0"
"6"     "3"     "1,2,3,4"       "0"
"7"     "3"     "1,2,3,4"       "0"
"8"     "4"     "1,2,3,4"       "20" 
"9"     "10"    "1,2,3,4,8"     "5" // These type 10 are books
"10"    "10"    "1,2,3,4,8"     "5" // These type 10 are books
"11"    "10"    "1,2,3,4,8"     "5" // These type 10 are books
"12"    "10"    "1,2,3,4,8"     "5" // These type 10 are books
```

**This is stored procedure I'm using**

```
BEGIN
#---- Updater for like totals 21-11-2013

   # Declare variables
   DECLARE procId, procLikes INT(10);
   DECLARE procPath VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

   # Declare cursor
   DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, path, likes FROM testLikes WHERE type = 10;

   # Declare Handle
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

   # Open Cursor
   OPEN cur1;

   # Begin the Loop
   the_loop: LOOP

    FETCH cur1 INTO procId, procPath, procLikes;

   IF done THEN
    LEAVE the_loop;
   END IF;

   # Do some post processing
    UPDATE testLikes t1 JOIN testLikes t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.path)
        SET t1.likes = t1.likes + procLikes // Trying to add a sum(of all type = 10) here.
            // Problem here is, New totals should be sum of all type = 10, but right now, it all adds up.
            WHERE t2.id = procId;

    END LOOP the_loop;

    # Dummy select for MySql's bug
    SELECT id INTO procId FROM testLikes where id = 1;

    CLOSE cur1;

END
```

Comment: One of the principles of database normalization is to not store calculated values.

Comment: related to your comment- "how to setup a stored procedure on sqlfiddle to demo it." check this

Execute triggers stored procedures on SqlFiddle. Mysql http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-triggers-stored-procedures-on-sqlfiddle-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully convinced if that works, but:

```
 select
type
,SUM(likes) as NUmberofLikes
into temp1
from testLikes
group by type

UPDATE testlikes t1
SET likes= (select NumberOFLikes from temp1 t2 where t1.type=t2.type)
```