# Unable to use declare statement in CREATE FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, sqlfiddle

I am trying to use a `declare [variable]` statement within a `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

My code is

```
/* DELIMITER // */

CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
  RETURNS TEXT
DECLARE bae int;
BEGIN
  RETURN 'Hello World';
END;
//
/* DELIMITER ; */
```

The code just worked fine without using declare, but with the declare it gives me the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use...

How can I actually use the declare statement inside function or stored procedure?

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with SQL Fiddle for examples like this. I'm going to try [installing mysql locally](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/), and I suggest you do the same.

Comment: sql fiddle doesn't support `DECLARE`

Comment: a local install is the way to go. phil's method is good, personally I have a linux vm in virtual box, and connect to it using sqlyog (https://www.webyog.com/). sqlyog isn't free, work bench is (https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't comment out the delimiter, and declares need to be immediately after the begin statement:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world() RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE bae INT;
  RETURN 'Hello World';
END
//
DELIMITER; --restore delimiter

SELECT hello_world() --Hello World
```

**EDIT:**

I've never used sql fiddle. I've played with it for 5 minutes and I hate it :)

Apparantly, sql fiddle has different syntax rules. The one that applies here is that they do not support delimiters, but do have `//` built in as a "known delimiter" ([Execute triggers stored procedures on SqlFiddle. Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-triggers-stored-procedures-on-sqlfiddle-mysql))

So, this works:

```
CREATE function hello_world() returns text
BEGIN
declare bae int;
return "hello world";
END//

select hello_world()
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e5da4/1

So, there is a working fiddle. I hand-typed the function and it works. HOWEVER, I literally copy pasted that into a new sqlfiddle and I get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3

So this inconsistant behavior is pretty annoying.

Comment: @PhilWalton it works at the first time when i copy paste and when i just use int in case of varchar it returns error ..seems like there is some problem with sqlfiddle

Comment: see updated answer. I had the same problem. It only worked when I hand typed it, broke when I copy pasted. sql fiddle sorta sucks apparently....

Comment: @PhilWalton NP. sqlfiddle is a great concept, but I won't ever use it unless glitches like this are ironed out

Answer (score 0):

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), you preface each declaration with `declare`, inside the `begin`-`end` block:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hello_world()
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE bae int;
    RETURN 'Hello World';
END;
```

Comment: still the same error ....it would be helpful if you can give me the example as sql fiddle